# Retrieving salt stored as plaintext alongside ciphertext using C#

Tags: c#, string, encryption, salt

I am writing a C# app designed to encrypt text files using Rijndeal (block size 128, key size 256, in other words AES256). I use the user supplied password and a random salt to generate a key using PBKDF2. (The IV is also derived from the password and salt)

I want to store the salt as cleartext prepended to the ciphertext. In other words, line 1 would contain something like `>>>SALTGOESHERE`. Line 3 and onward would store the ciphertext.

How should I go about retrieving the salt for decryption?

I'm very new to C#, this is my first real app, so please bear with my ignorance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yourString.Substring(0, yourString.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine));`

change 0 to 3 if ">>>" is not just the placeholder

Comment: Oh yea! I think that would work perfectly. I originally planned to use regex. So that's what the >>> is for. I don't need it with this though. Let me test it before I accept the answer. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Razick - np, post any follow up question if you have, otherwise don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you...

Comment: Worked great. I got an error when using yourString.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) so I used this instead: yourString.Substring(17, 24); 17 accounts for "SALT(REQUIRED): " while 24 accounts for the salt. Thank you!

Comment: The error was caused by me applying the method to the password instead of cryptotext/salt. Wooopsie.